# Powershell - does not transmit the result to the report html

Tags: html, powershell

Ok, i change my code. Now data are loaded directly into the html and not saved to a file and later converted to the email as html table.
This is my new code:

```
Function Get-ComInfo
{   
    param(
            $computers
        )

    #Here LOW Space thresold is lessthan 10% of the total size of the Volume
    $PercentFree = @{Name="FreeSpace(GB)";Expression={"{0:N1}" -f($_.freespace /1GB)}} 
Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -filter "DriveType=3" -computer $computers -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue|
Select SystemName,DeviceID,VolumeName,$PercentFree,@{Name="Size(GB)";Expression={"{0:N1}" -f($_.size/1gb)}},@{name="PercentFree(%)";Expression={int}}

}
$html= 
"
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN'  'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head>
<title>HTML TABLE</title>
 <style type='text/css'>
  .alert {{
    background-color: #FB1717 }}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<colgroup><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/></colgroup>
"

Get-Content U:\Users\XXX\Desktop\servers.txt  | ForEach-Object {
    if(!(test-connection -computername $_ -quiet -count 1))
    {

        $html += "<tr><td>$_</td><td>Offline</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>"
    }
    else
    {

   # $entries = Get-Content U:\Users\XXX\Desktop\servers.txt | % { Get-ComInfo -computers $_ } |  ForEach-Object {
   Get-ComInfo -computers $_ |  ForEach-Object {
        if ([float]::Parse($_.'FreeSpace(GB)') -le 5)
        {
            #$alertEntryTemplate -f $_.SystemName, $_.DeviceID, $_.VolumeName, $_.'FreeSpace(GB)', $_.'Size(GB)', $_.'PercentFree(%)', $_.'LOW SPACE'
            $html += "<tr class='alert'><tr><td>$_.SystemName</td><td>$_.DeviceID</td><td>$_.VolumeName</td><td>$_.'FreeSpace(GB)'</td><td>$_.'Size(GB)'</td><td>$_.'PercentFree(%)'</td><td>$_.'LOW SPACE'</td></tr>"
        }
        else
        {
            #$entryTemplate -f $_.SystemName, $_.DeviceID, $_.VolumeName, $_.'FreeSpace(GB)', $_.'Size(GB)', $_.'PercentFree(%)', $_.'LOW SPACE'
            $html += "<tr><td>$_.SystemName</td><td>$_.DeviceID</td><td>$_.VolumeName</td><td>$_.'FreeSpace(GB)'</td><td>$_.'Size(GB)'</td><td>$_.'PercentFree(%)'</td><td>$_.'LOW SPACE'</td></tr>"
        }
    }
}
}
$html += 
"
</table>
</body>
</html>
" 
$SMTPServer = "smtp.XXX.XXX" 
$EmailFrom = "XXX@XXX.XXX"
$EmailTo = "XXX@XXX.XXX"
$Subject = "$computers PROGRES ;))"  
$body = $html
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 25) 
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $false
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("XXX", "XXX");

$msg.Body = $html
$msg = New-object Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $body)
$msg.IsBodyHTML = $true 
$SMTPClient.Send($msg)
```

And my email reprot look bad, I`s not frmated, and i dont know why?

```
@{SystemName=K005; DeviceID=U:; VolumeName=Nowy; FreeSpace(GB)=87,4; Size(GB)=465,8; PercentFree(%)=}.SystemName    @{SystemName=K005; DeviceID=U:; VolumeName=Nowy; FreeSpace(GB)=87,4; Size(GB)=465,8; PercentFree(%)=}.DeviceID  @{SystemName=K005; DeviceID=U:; VolumeName=New; FreeSpace(GB)=87,4; Size(GB)=465,8; PercentFree(%)=}.VolumeName @{SystemName=K005; DeviceID=U:; VolumeName=Nowy; FreeSpace(GB)=87,4; Size(GB)=465,8; PercentFree(%)=}.'FreeSpace(GB)'   @{SystemName=K005; DeviceID=U:; VolumeName=New; FreeSpace(GB)=87,4; Size(GB)=465,8; PercentFree(%)=}.'Size(GB)' @{SystemName=K005; DeviceID=U:; VolumeName=Nowy; FreeSpace(GB)=87,4; Size(GB)=465,8; PercentFree(%)=}.'PercentFree(%)'  @{SystemName=K005; DeviceID=U:; VolumeName=Nowy; FreeSpace(GB)=87,4; Size(GB)=465,8; PercentFree(%)=}.'LOW SPACE'
XXX Offline             
XXX Offline
```

Why is it not formated? I was able to do what I wanted before ( or unsubscribe XXX Offline in the report ) , but now to me it does not format as it was before.

Comment: I didn't go through the entire code or didn't do a test run however, prima facie it looks like you have defined a function inside Else block and never called.. You may check on that part.

Comment: But email raport is formed without a problem . Not only writes XXX offline.

Comment: It is showing only "XXX Offline" because that is part of the `if(!(test-connection -computername $_ -quiet -count 1)) { ... } `, whereas when your code enters the Else { } block, it finds only the definition of the function not any code to execute it. You can try to define the function somewhere outside of Else {} block in the script and call it inside the Else block by passing the parameter.

Comment: hmm , that is, I do not know how to do it . I need to think .

Comment: But showing XXX Offline at powershell console, not in raport html. I just like to pass a parameter to the function `if(!(test-connection -computername $_ -quiet -count 1)){
        $StatusTest -f "$_ offline" }` to print out the report in html . I do not know if I understand correctly .

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you for your commitment.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to the code but didn't test it. This is just to give you an idea about how to proceed with next steps to achieve what you want. Please make necessary changes as required.

```
Function Get-ComInfo
{   
    param(
            $computers
        )

    #Here LOW Space thresold is lessthan 10% of the total size of the Volume
    Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -filter "DriveType=3" -computer $computers -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue|
    Select SystemName,DeviceID,VolumeName,`
    @{Name="FreeSpace(GB)";Expression={[Math]::Round($_.FreeSpace /1GB,2)}},`
    @{Name="Size(GB)";Expression={[Math]::Round($_.Size/1gb,2)}},`
    @{Name="PercentFree(%)";Expression={[Math]::Round(($_.FreeSpace*100/$_.Size)/1gb,2)}}
}


$html=
@'
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>HTML TABLE</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  .alert {{
    background-color: #FB1717 }}
  </style>
  <style type="text/css">
  .status {{
    background-color: #FEFE33 }}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<colgroup><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>SystemName</th><th>DeviceID</th><th>VolumeName</th><th>Size(GB)</th><th>FreeSpace(GB)</th></tr>
{0}
</table>
</body></html>
'@

$entryTemplate = '<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td><td>{3}</td><td>{4}</td><td>{5}</td><td>{6}</td></tr>'
$alertEntryTemplate = '<tr class="alert"><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td><td>{3}</td><td>{4}</td><td>{5}</td><td>{6}</td></tr>'
$StatusTest = '<tr><td>{0}</td></tr>'


Get-Content U:\Users\xxx\Desktop\servers.txt  | 
ForEach-Object
{
    if(!(test-connection -computername $_ -quiet -count 1))
    {
        $StatusTest -f "$_ offline"
    }
    else
    {
    }
    $entries = Get-Content U:\Users\xxx\Desktop\servers.txt | % { Get-ComInfo -computers $_ } | 
    ForEach-Object
    {
        if ([float]::Parse($_.'FreeSpace(GB)') -le 5)
        {
            $alertEntryTemplate -f $_.SystemName, $_.DeviceID, $_.VolumeName, $_.'FreeSpace(GB)', $_.'Size(GB)', $_.'PercentFree(%)', $_.'LOW SPACE'
        }
        else
        {
            $entryTemplate -f $_.SystemName, $_.DeviceID, $_.VolumeName, $_.'FreeSpace(GB)', $_.'Size(GB)', $_.'PercentFree(%)', $_.'LOW SPACE'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There seems to be an issue with HTML output that is being generated. Just try to see (Write-Host) what output you get through $html as a final result.

Comment: Write-Host It is also not configured.As in email.